# Play framework with OpenID

Tags: playframework

Hey I'm using play framework and for the login I am using OpenID. The problem is up until now i used version 2.2.1 and it worked but once I moved to version 2.2.3 it gives me this error: "ConnectException: General SSLEngine problem". Does anyone has a clue why is that? I can give code if needed but it is just from the play documentation, nothing special.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is full authentication/authorization stack available as a module - [Play Authenticate](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/)

It allows you to register users with many providers, also with OpenID or just an email. Additionally there's support for multilanguage, template customization (also in emails) etc. Finally it's shipped originally with DeadBolt2 - authorization solution with roles and users permissions.

You can checkout sample application for more details.